# Using MediarR for projects that has no database?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I am a new at MediatR user of .net core platform. And I read that is a nice solution to implement CQRS pattern. So my project does not use any database. And it dows only query from Elasticsearch. So Can I use MediatR in this project and is it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when Database does not exists in solution it is not affected to MediatR and CQRS, because Database it is just a way to store you data (it can be simple List for example instead). MediatR with IRequest and IRequestHandler gives you another layer between view and domain. **So answer is**: yes you can use MediatR library/pattern in your solution.

Simple advice: **NO complex logic** in your controller methods. MediatR can help with this